# rotating an overlay view in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have an overlay view (Which has self-drawn shapes) that I display over an ImageView. I want the view to be movable, resizable, and rotatable. I could allow the user to move the overlay by dragging it from the middle, or resize it by dragging it from one of two sides (right or bottom). What I still could not do is to allow the user to rotate it by moving the left-top edge.

```
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle * M_PI / 180);
```

But how can I calculate the *angle* based on user touches? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` which gives you the rotation value as a property.

If you can't use a gesture recognizer, try something like this (untested):

```
// Assuming centerPoint is the center point of the object you want to rotate (the rotation axis),
// currentTouchLocation and initialTouchLocation are the coordinates of the points between 
// which you want to calculate the angle.
CGPoint centerPoint = ...
CGPoint currentTouchLocation = ...
CGPoint initialTouchLocation = ...

// Convert to polar coordinates with the centerPoint being (0,0)
CGPoint currentTouchLocationNormalized = CGPointMake(currentTouchLocation.x - centerPoint.x, currentTouchLocation.y - centerPoint.y);
CGPoint initialTouchLocationNormalized = CGPointMake(initialTouchLocation.x - centerPoint.x, initialTouchLocation.y - centerPoint.y);

CGFloat angleBetweenInitialTouchAndCenter = atan2(initialTouchLocationNormalized.y, initialTouchLocationNormalized.x);
CGFloat angleBetweenCurrentTouchAndCenter = atan2(currentTouchLocationNormalized.y, currentTouchLocationNormalized.x);

CGFloat rotationAngle = angleBetweenCurrentTouchAndCenter - angleBetweenInitialTouchAndCenter;
```

See Wikipedia or do a Google search to learn more about polar coordinates and how to convert between cartesian and polar coordinate systems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. unfortunately, the Gestures do not provide me with the user interaction experience that I prefer. For example, it is not possible with gestures to increase the width and fix the height of the view. Additionally, If I use the gestures, I will not be able to move the overlay using a single finger.